# Copy value into rows below until greater value is found in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on copying first sequential value in "episode" until another value > than itself is found(see column "episode_final" below) without too much luck. The logic should partition the data by id ordered by date in SQL server 2012. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: sample_edited]

Comment: Your image didn't work, Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Share your code you attempted.

Comment: D-Shih - Is it working now?

Comment: Images of data are really not very useful. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @user2823833 Yes, I can see the image now

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function get the `episode`  next value.

Then use `CASE WHEN` check `episode> nextVal` does increase 1.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  id varchar(50),
  date date,
  episode int
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-01',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-02',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-10',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-11',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-12',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-01-20',2);  
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-03-20',1);  
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-05-01',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-05-10',3); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (123,'2018-05-20',1); 
INSERT INTO T VALUES (345,'2018-06-20',1);  
INSERT INTO T VALUES (345,'2018-07-21',1);  
INSERT INTO T VALUES (345,'2018-07-22',2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT  t1.Id,
           t1.Date,
           t1.episode,
         (SUM(CASE WHEN episode> coalesce(nextVal,preVal) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over (partition by id order by [date]) + 1)  episode_final
    FROM (
      SELECT T.*,LEAD(episode) over (partition by id  order by  [date]) nextVal,
      LAG(episode) over (partition by id  order by  [date]) preVal
      FROM T 
    )t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8002a/2/0)**:

```
|  Id |       Date | episode | episode_final |
|-----|------------|---------|---------------|
| 123 | 2018-01-01 |       1 |             1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-02 |       1 |             1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-10 |       1 |             1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-11 |       1 |             1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-12 |       1 |             1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-20 |       2 |             2 |
| 123 | 2018-03-20 |       1 |             2 |
| 123 | 2018-05-01 |       1 |             2 |
| 123 | 2018-05-10 |       3 |             3 |
| 123 | 2018-05-20 |       1 |             3 |
| 345 | 2018-06-20 |       1 |             1 |
| 345 | 2018-07-21 |       1 |             1 |
| 345 | 2018-07-22 |       2 |             2 |
```